# Resource reference with name 'XXXX' not found for this EJB or interceptor

Tags: ejb, interceptor

I'm facing this issue right now in my project. I had migrated from EJB 2.1 to 3.0 when I did so RSA sent me an error like this one

```
Resource reference with name 'XXXX' not found for this EJB or interceptor
```

Why this is happening? Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide some sample code, configurations and any other relevant information?